# Adicionar Item e Index no combobox

Tags: vba, excel-vba, combobox, macro

Olá, gostaria de inserir em um combobox o Item e o index desse Item.

O item (nome_funcionario) eu faço através de uma consulta em um banco de dados e eu queria que o index fosse o id_funcionario.

Eu já tentei de diversas formas e não consegui.

OBS: O Erro que ele causa é "Era esperado: = "

Segue o Código abaixo.

```html
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim TotalCursos As Variant

'Parametrização do Banco de Dados
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
strDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SistemaGerenciamento.accdb"
cn.ConnectionString = _
          "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strDB & ";"
cn.Open


strSQL = "SELECT id_funcionario, nome_funcionario FROM tbl_funcionario"
 
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        
        cmb_funcionario.AddItem (rs("nome_Funcionario"),rs("id_funcionario"))
        
    rs.MoveNext
    
    Loop

cn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesta linha:

```
cmb_funcionario.AddItem (rs("nome_Funcionario"),rs("id_funcionario"))
```

Retire o parenteses, voce adc. a virgula mas colocou dentro do parenteses fazendo com que o metodo AddItem entenda como somente um parametro.
Agora o Erro sobre: "Era esperado: = " entende se que voce esta fazendo uma operação entre *(rs("nome_Funcionario"),rs("id_funcionario"))*. E não entendo o que vc quer com a vigula e lhe retorna o erro.

Logo o esperado deveria ser:

```
cmb_funcionario.AddItem rs("nome_Funcionario"),rs("id_funcionario")
```

Note que o Index é somente a ordem que os itens aparecem na combobox. E dependendo a ordem que os registros foram cadastrados pode causar transtorno para o usuario.